# gmp (Multiple Precision Arithmetic) apply.bigz function error

Tags: r

Using the example in its help page:

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigz(matrix(1:12,3))
apply(x,1,min)
# Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 3:
# [1] 1 2 3
apply(x,2,max)
# Big Integer ('bigz') object of length 3:
# [1] 10 11 12
```

The results should be:

```
x <- matrix(1:12,3)
apply(x,1,min)
# [1] 1 2 3
apply(x,2,max)
# [1]  3  6  9 12
```

Comment: Seems like a bug that you should report to the package maintainer. What is your question?

Comment: BTW, `apply(x, 0, max)` sees to work by columns; I guess the "MARGIN" argument might be interpreted as logical but is not documented as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works ok now!!

```
x <- matrix(1:12,3)
apply(x,1,min)
# [1] 1 2 3
apply(x,2,max)
# [1]  3  6  9 12
```